# CakePHPのメール内でhtmlHelperを使う方法

Tags: php, cakephp

メールの中で`<?php echo $this->Html->Link() ?>`を使いたいのですが、どこでHelperを読み込ませたら良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP のバージョンによってやり方が違うので注意してください。
以下は CakePHP 2.x の場合です。

CakeEmail クラスには以下のメソッドがあります。
[CakeEmail::helpers()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-CakeEmail.html#_helpers)
これによって、メール本文の .ctp ファイルでヘルパー群を使用することが可能になります。
以下は一例です。

```
App::uses( 'CakeEmail', 'Network/Email' );
$mail_address = 'example@example.com';
$cakeEmail = new CakeEmail();
$mailResponse = $email->config( 'default' )
->helpers( 'Html' ) // ← HTML ヘルパを読み込ませる
->viewVars( array('address'=>$mail_address) )
->to( $mail_address );

try
{
    $cakeEmail->send();
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    // 例外処理
}
```